# How to get the text inside a h2 tag in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, assertion

how to get the text inside the html tag and assert if it is present on the page.

html-

```
<h2>  You are suggested the Low Fat Vegan Diet </h2>
```

i tried-

```
message = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2').Text()
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Text'

```
 message = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2').getText()
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getText'

how do i get the text and assert it is present in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the method name is  `find_elements_by_tag_name` so it returns a list of `elements`.
if your target element is the first item in elements you can try this:

```
message = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')[0].text
```

i recommend you to use [Beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to get better search in elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the full HTML, but if you have multiple h2 elements you will need to iterate through them to get the text.

```
message = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
for i in message:
    print(i.text)
```

Otherwise, you should be able to select the text with `.text`

```
message = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2').text
```

Comment: Thanks , i have only one h2 tag. It worked with the below answer provided by adding the index value

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
//h2[contains(text(),'String value')]
```